# How do i view the log/console for the J2EE Preview server/container in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, struts

I'm working on a struts2 web app in Eclipse, and am using the built-in J2EE Preview server.
How can i view the logs / console for it?

I'm having some problems and now my previously working site is showing Error 404 everywhere, and the console tab at the bottom window of eclipse isn't showing anything.

Cheers all

edit: Here's some screenshots of my console and servers tabs in eclipse:
[Console http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/2522/console.gif](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/2522/console.gif)
[Servers http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/3302/servers.gif](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/3302/servers.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i gave up and downloaded and installed tomcat and used it as my preview server. The console has much more informative stack traces with tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

There are two buttons on the right side of the `Console` in Eclipse:

- Display Selected Console (a picture of a monitor)
- Open Console - a picture of an application window

Try changing their drop-down values to find your needed console.
That's of course if your setup is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I've attached screenshots above of my console tab to show what i can see. I tried working those two buttons you mentioned but i'm sure i've got it set to the correct console because i can see the 'starting preview server' message.